# Unexpected '@' in program with User Defined Settings in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Following user defined setting is declared on Xcode ,

```
TEST_STRING = \@\"Test String\"
```

Declared following on preprocessor macro section ,

```
TEST_STRING = $(TEST_STRING)
```

However when I try to use this , getting a build failure with

> "Unexpected '@' in program"

Program compiles without the whitespace in the string,

```
TEST_STRING = \@\"TestString\"
```

Is there any other way I can have a string on user defined settings which supports white spaces ?

Comment: What do you mean by "user defined settings"?

Comment: xcode - > Choose Your Target --- > Build Settings -- > User-Defined section

Comment: It might just be easier to put them into a header file, perhaps using `#ifdef` etc?

Comment: I have couple of other parameters declared same way , so I need everything to be in same place . :)

Comment: Header file sounds perfect then...

Comment: I have about 8 targets , so 8 header files for each target? .  Also I like to whats causing this build failure ?

Comment: This is where the `#ifdef` comes in.  Basically you are battling the command line (shell) as you want to pass complex strings through to the compiler and therefore need to escape spaces etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to escape the whitespace character:

```
\@\"Test\ String\"
```

For example, `NSLog(TEST_STRING);` will give you `Test String` in the console

Comment: Why does the `@` need to be escaped?